# How to extract small part of the email body in Outlook using Python?

Tags: python, regex, outlook, pywin32

I am trying to automate the extraction of information from the body of standard mails in my outlook.
I need to extract following info:

- code
- number1
- number3

And then transfer it to an excel file.

But for now I would like to know how to access this information in a mail body.

This is an example of an standard mail:

```
Subject: Test1

Hi,
You got a new answer from user Alex. 
 
Code: alex123fj
Number1: 0611111111
Number2: 1020
Number3: 3032
```

This my code (I filtered mails so that I can access only mails that I got within 1 day):

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
messages = messages.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'answers@gmail.com'")
messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Test1'")

message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use regex example*

*https://regex101.com/r/b2t5iw/1*

---

*Code example with selected email*

```
import re
import win32com.client


def get_body(Item):
    try:
        print(Item.Subject)
        body = Item.body
        matches = re.finditer(r"Code:\s(.*)$", body, re.MULTILINE)
        for match in matches:
            print("Code: ", match.group(1))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    Items = Outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection
    Item = Items(1)
    get_body(Item)
```

---

*should print*

> `Code:  alex123fj`